# Need to show download and delete buttons for the files generated through API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, webforms, datatables-1.10

I tried to display table with list of items from API url by consuming it. And in addition to that i tried to add download and delete column. Which should show download and delete buttons on each row of that table.

Successfully pulled list in table format and displayed in .aspx page. But failed to show download and delete button.

Below is the output i got so far. My target is to get download and delete buttons on each row.

[image]

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridView1();
}
}

private void BindGridView1()
    {
        string apiUrl = "http://mesappbeta/BE_API_HOME/api/SeriesBlacklist/Req_UploadedDocs?series=AE01400&series_type=RU";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Root data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("File Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("File Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("Uploaded Date");

                foreach (var item in data.data)
                {
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["File Name"] = item.file_name;
                    row["File Type"] = item.file_type;
                    row["Uploaded Date"] = item.created_datetime;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                // Add TemplateField for Download button
                TemplateField downloadField = new TemplateField();
                downloadField.HeaderText = "Download";
                downloadField.ItemTemplate = new ButtonTemplate("Download", "<%# DownloadFile(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Container.DataItem[\"file_name\"].ToString())) %>");
                downloadField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                GridView2.Columns.Add(downloadField);

                // Add TemplateField for Delete button
                TemplateField deleteField = new TemplateField();
                deleteField.HeaderText = "Delete";
                deleteField.ItemTemplate = new ButtonTemplate("Delete", "<%# DeleteFile(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Container.DataItem[\"file_name\"].ToString())) %>");
                deleteField.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                GridView2.Columns.Add(deleteField);

                GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            DownloadFile(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            DeleteFile(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Below code is from class file

```
public class ButtonTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private string _buttonText;
    private string _clickMethod;        

    public ButtonTemplate(string buttonText, string clickMethod)
    {
        _buttonText = buttonText;
        _clickMethod = clickMethod;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        LinkButton btn = new LinkButton();
        btn.CommandName = "CustomCommand";
        btn.Text = _buttonText;
        btn.CommandArgument = _clickMethod;
        btn.ID = "lnkButton";
        btn.CssClass = "myButtonStyle"; // Add CSS class to the button
        container.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

below is the code of gridview in aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
```

</asp:GridView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me there is VERY little valid case for code behind to add the columns.

Since your code behind is hard coding the column names, then why not just add the two buttons to the GV?

You might get the buttons added with your code (but you have to re-inject all the time, not have automatic view state), and worse it will be even MORE difficult to add a click event to those 2 buttons.

So, why not dump all that work, and just add the 2 buttons to the gv markup, and be done with this?

eg this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
CssClass="table table-hover"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
Width="45%">

<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FullFile" HeaderText="Full File" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="File Size" HeaderText="Size" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" Text="DownLoad" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdDelete_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You have BOAT loads more flexibility here.

And thus we get + see this:

[image]

And big bonues?

Then the click event becomes REALLY easy to pick up the current row.

Say delete button code:

```
    protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmdDel= (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cmdDel.NamingContainer;

        Debug.Print($"Row index = {gRow.RowIndex.ToString()}");
        Debug.Print($"File name of this row = {gRow.Cells[1].Text}");
        // do whatever to delete here
    }
```

output:

```
Row index = 3
File name of this row = dd.min.js
```

So, it not clear at this point that you made a strong case to write all that code when you don't need to write ANY code to add those 2 buttons to the columns.

The other big advantage is you can use say a image button, or even bootstrap icons if you want. (say use a link button) like this:

[image]

But, we "enjoy" a plain jane button click event for each row.

So, it not really clear why the goal exists to inject + write code for the buttons and controls you can simple drag + drop into that page.

## Edit: Have delete row remove that row

Well, with that requirement, then we need to persist the data we "feed" to the data table. So, then the "details" of where and how the data for the data table was obtained becomes the issue.

but, to simple "remove" the current row clicked on?

Sure, then I suggest we persist the data table, and if that dt only has say 5-10 rows, then I would consider view state. If it has more rows, then I would perist the data to session().

Lets use session() here then. So, the code to load becomes this:

(it don't matter where the data came from), but only that we persist. IN my example, I using files in a folder list.

So, say this code to load same as before, but RIGHT before we bind the gv, we do this:

```
        Session["MyTable"] = MyTable;

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

So, now our delete button code then is this:

```
    protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmdDel= (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cmdDel.NamingContainer;

        Debug.Print($"Row index = {gRow.RowIndex.ToString()}");
        Debug.Print($"File name of this row = {gRow.Cells[1].Text}");
        // do whatever to delete here
        // remove row from table

        DataTable MyTable = (DataTable)Session["MyTable"];

        MyTable.Rows[gRow.RowIndex].Delete();   
        MyTable.AcceptChanges();
        GridView1.DataSource= MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

So, we simple remove the row from the table, and re-bind the gv.

Comment: thank you so much Albert. It worked and yeah, i was learning c# so thought of giving a try to load table through c# instead of <columns> tag

Comment: there are cases for "adding" or injecting controls. But, I did "push" quite hard the point that in most cases it not worth it. The real "gemstone" here is note how easy the click event can get the current row information. That "alone" makes it worth it to just drop in the extra two buttons - and using that "naming container" approach makes this all rather easy.  And to be really fair? PHP, and even .net core pages? yes, rather common to write code to "inject" or "add" controls. but, webforms? No, it don't like that "add" controls very much - (so we use repeaters, or gridview etc.).

Comment: can you please help me with code for download and delete also. I was trying but getting stuck. Download/delete should be from api url. Not from folders.

Comment: i figured code for download, i'm working on delete code

Comment: is delete code to just remove the item from the GV, or does it have to do more? but, deleting the "row" from the GV is easy, and I would assume that perhaps more is required.  To delete the row? Then I would persist the data table and then thus just remove the row from the dt, and then re-bind to the gv. I'll post a example in 5 minutes

Comment: So, see the edit. I show how to remove the one row from the GV. However, I have to assume some other api or some other call to "where ever" to delete the file would be required. But, note how the simple button click gets the row index, of which then I can get the file name, and then remove the row, or do whatever, including that of removing the row from the data and then re-binding the GV. So, operate on the data "source" of the GV, not the gv.